# is posible send params in .env file node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have my file users.env inner routes/querys/users.env

```
 module.exports = {
  GET_USERS: "SELECT * FROM users",
  CREATE_USER: "INSERT INTO users ("id", "first_name", "last_name", "active") VALUES (NULL, '%PARAM1%', '%PARAM2%', '1');"
}
```

Is possible send params1 and params 2 to .env file and return complete string?
I could  get env var string incomplete and after create function to replace %PARAMS_1% to value, but I need other option

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
module.exports = (param1, param2) => {
  GET_USERS: "SELECT * FROM users",
  CREATE_USER: (!!param1 && !!param2) ? 
    `INSERT INTO users ("id", "first_name", "last_name", "active") VALUES (NULL, '${param1}', '${param2}', '1');` : 
    "INSERT INTO users (\"id\", \"first_name\", \"last_name\", \"active\") VALUES (NULL, '%PARAM1%', '%PARAM2%', '1');"
}
```

Take in 2 parameters in the require and concatenate them in the string or return the original values if the parameters passed in are falsy. You would need to change the calling code to use something like:

```
const userFunctions = require('./env')(); // raw string
const populatedUserFunctions = require('./env')('hello', 'world'); // with param1 and param2
```